# Match multiple line comment blocks composed of one or more single line comments

Tags: regex, plaintext

I need a regex that will match comment blocks composed of one or more single line comments.

Single Line Comment:

```
# This is a single line comment
```

Comment Block Composed of Multiple Single Line Comments:

```
# This is a multiple line comment
# which is just a block of single line comments
# that are strung together
```

The first character of a comment line can begin with any of the following characters: `;#%|*`

I have found the following regex matches individual comment lines: `[;#%|*]{1}(.+)`

But I cannot figure out how to match for blocks that have more than one line.
I want to keep all characters in the whole block, including new lines.

Comment: your second example is not multi-line comment IMO, it is multiple single line comments

Comment: Fair enough. I edited the text above that block to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the start of a comment, the rest of its line, then repeat 0 or more occurences of a group which starts with a newline, optional spaces, followed by the a comment start character and the rest of the line:

```
[;#%|*].*(?:(?:\r\n|\r|\n) *[;#%|*].*)*
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tpe43D/2).

- `[;#%|*]` - Initial comment character
- `.*` - Rest of first line
- `(?:(?:\r\n|\r|\n) *[;#%|*].*)*` - Repeat 0 or more times:

  - `(?:\r\n|\r|\n)` - Newline (if you know the format of your newline characters in advance, you can simplify this, eg, perhaps to just `\n`)
  - space followed by * - 0 or more spaces
  - `[;#%|*]` - Initial comment character
  - `.*` - Rest of line

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that here we might want an expression that'd pass newlines, such as

```
[;#%|*]([\s\S].*?)(?=[\r\n])
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/3gwMv2/1/)

Comment: I tried your suggestion on some sample text and it selects everything in the file after the first comment block right to the end of file.

Comment: At the moment your version is matching the single line comments but not the multiple lines as a block. I found the answer by @certainperformance works for me.